# Give Address fields and get Longtitude and Latitude

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, address

I have created 4 fields on event object (Street, City, Country, Postal Code). I want to display all the events in a map by using lightning:map at a custom lightning component. Today i realized that if i have more than 10 events on the map, some of them are not displayed in the map. And i read that i shoud get the longtitude and latitude. More specifically, i read that:

- i can specify a maximum of 10 geocoded address lookups per map.
  Lookups for both the mapMarkers and center attributes count toward
  this limit. To display more markers, provide location values using a
  pair of latitude and longitude coordinates, which don't require
  geocoding. Address locations that exceed the geocoding limit are
  ignored.

**So my question is if there is a chance to get the geolocation by giving the address, for free.**

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. However, the specific solution depends on what you're trying to do specifically. The more specific the question, the better we can help you with a relevant answer. Please [edit] your question to include more information, such as what the purpose is, when the data needs to be available, what research you've done so far, etc.

Comment: Ok sfdcfox, i edit it immediately.